# Why to use Picasso/or some other library over Okhttp?

Tags: android, picasso, okhttp

I am still discovering funcionalities of both, but I have one question on my mind.

**Why to use Picasso over OkHttp?**

OkHttp supports pretty much the same thing as picasso, is just that picasso is simpler to use for loading and caching images....

Is there some other important thing that I miss, and that is not included in OkHttp?

And if I use Picasso, do I still need to import OkHttp or it is already included in picasso?

Comment: "... just that `x` is simpler to use for `y`" is the reason for every library ever written

Comment: thats right yes, but I was wondering if there is some additional feature that is definetly not supported in OkHttp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picasso is an image downloading and caching library for Android.

OkHttp is HTTP & HTTP/2 client for Android and Java applications.

So, the libraries have completely different purposes. Picasso is completely focused on the image handling. For instance, you cannot use OkHttp to resize an image...to define the crop model to apply...etc

You can use Picasso with OkHttp if you want.

Comment: Ok, that is right, they have different purpose... But I can do also image downloading with OkHttp without using Picasso.... is there some functionality that piccasso has and that OkHttp does not have? 
Also could you answer me the last question?

Comment: Resize an image, define the crop model, define a placeholder and an error image...Check the features tab here: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: ok tnx! And do I need to include OkHttp if I use Picasso? Or is already included with picasso?

Comment: No, You don't need. Picasso can handle the network requests without external dependencies.

Comment: OkHttp adds a disk cache. So you get the best behavior if you use ’em together.

Comment: A few things that an image loading library do on top of abstracting the http calls:

1. Provide cache (not-I/O) holding.

2. Provide transformation (between response and cache) APIs.

2. Auto-cancel callbacks that fulfill the equals and hash code contract.